# A self-adjoint operator related to prime numbers?

Tags: functional-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

I originally posted this question on MO, but since it might not be research related, I deleted it and posted it here again:

Consider the completely additive function $\eta(n) := \sum_{p\mid n} v_p(n)p$ defined on natural numbers, with values in natural numbers. For literature, on this function, see [the corresponding OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A001414). Consider the Gram matrix:

$$G(n) := (k(a,b))_{1 \le a,b \le n}$$

where

$$k(a,b) = \eta(\gcd(a,b))$$

might be a positive semi definite kernel on the natural numbers, if one can find an embedding  $\phi(n)$ for each natural number $n$in the Hilbert space of sequence over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ such that we have $k(a,b) = \langle \phi(a),\phi(b) \rangle$

**Q0: Is there an embedding $\phi$ which does this?**

The game for the natural numbers is like this:

Given two natural numbers $a,b$, what is the minimal cost of a series transformation from $a$ to $b$. A transformation is multiplication / division with a prime number $p$ and its cost is $p$. For a series of transformations, the cost is the sum of transformations in the series. (Spoiler: The answer is independent from the chosen series and is

$\eta(\frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)^2})$

which can be seen by introducing a graph $G = (\mathbb{N},E)$ on the natural numbers, where the edges $a \approx b$ are defined through

$$(a,b) \in E \iff \frac{a}{b} \text{ or } \frac{b}{a} \text{ is prime}$$

with weights on the edges equal to $w((a,b)) := \max\{a/b,b/a\} = $ a prime number.

A path from $a$ to $b$ corresponds to a series of transformations in the game above, and a shortest path, corresponds to a series of transformations of minimal cost.

The connection to the graph and the Gram matrix is given by the shortest path distance:

$$d_s(a,b) = \eta( \frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)^2} ) = \eta(a)+\eta(b)-2\eta(\gcd(a,b)) = |\phi(a) - \phi(b)|_H^2 = d_H(a,b)^2$$

where the subscript $H$ denotes the Hilbert space of series.

It is fun and somewhat surprising to look at the spectrum $\sigma(G(n))$ of these Gram matrices (Here for example $n=169$):

[image: Here we see the spectrum of G(169)]. One can recognize three parts:

$$\sigma(G(n)) = \sigma_p \cup \sigma_c \cup \sigma_0$$

where $\sigma_p := \{ \lambda \in \sigma(G(n)) \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{N} , n/2 < \lambda \le n \}$ and

$\sigma_c := \{ \lambda \in \sigma(G(n)) \mid \lambda \notin \mathbb{N} , n/2 < \lambda \le n \}$ and $\sigma_0 := \{ \lambda \in \sigma(G(n)) \mid 0 \le \lambda \le n/2 \}$

Furthermore, looking at the numbers of $\sigma_p$ we recognize that these are exactly the prime numbers $p$ with $n/2 < p \le n$. That these prime numbers are a subset of $\sigma_p$ can be proven by observing that the $p$-th row and column in the Gram matrix consists of $0$s everywhere except at the diagonal where it has entry $p$. So by permuting this $p$-th column and then $p$-th row. We see that the matrix becomes a block-diagonal and can see that $n/2 < p \le n$ are eigenvalues. The off diagonal zeros can be explained because $k(a,p)  = \eta(\gcd(a,p)) = \eta(1) = 0$.
Using the embedding $\phi(n)$ we can define a linear operator $R(e_n) := \phi(e_n)$ on the standard basis $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $H$ and with this, we can define an unbounded, self-adjoint, linear and positive semidefinite operator on $H$:

$$O = R^* R $$

Searching for theorems and usages of unbounded, self-adjoint operators , I found Theorem 5.7 on Schmüdgen's "Unbounded self-adjoint operators on Hilber spaces":

Let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$. Then there exists a unique spectral measure $E = E_A$ on the Borel Sigma-algebra $B(\mathbb{R})$, such that:

$$A = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lambda \, d E_A(\lambda)$$

The idea is to transform $t$ to $t(1+t\cdot t)^{-1/2}$ to get from unboundend to bounded and backwards. However I am not sure, **if this theorem can be applied for $A=O$ as above, and if it can applied, if it is possible to compute the integral above directly? (Q1)**

In the German Wikipedia article of "spectra measure" there is an interesting observation from Quantum Mechanics of observables, which can be roughly divided in three parts:

1. the point spectrum ( one uses sums) [This would correspond I think to the prime numbers defined above]
2. the continuous spectrum (one uses integrals) [This would correspond to the $\sigma_c$ I think, $c$ for continuous.
3. very seldom there is a singular-continuous spetral part, which I think would correspond to $\sigma_0$.

**I am curious, if any of these observations can be proven? (Q2)**

The properties defining the kernel $k(a,b)=\eta(\gcd(a,b))$ are:
Suppose $k$ is a p.s.d kernel function (symmetric) on the natural numbers, such that:

1. $\gcd(a,b) = 1 \iff k(a,b) = 0$
2. $k(p^a,p^a) = ap$ for all primes $p$ and $a\ge 0$
3. $k\left(\frac{ac}{\gcd(a,c)^2},b\right) = k\left(\frac{a}{\gcd(a,c)},b\right) + k\left(\frac{c}{\gcd(a,c)},b\right)$

**Q3: I am interested and it would be cool, if anything can be said in the case when $n \rightarrow \infty$ for the spectrum of the operator $O = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} G(n)$?**

Comment: There is never a reason to add a spoiler tag to a question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I have removed the spoiler tag from the question.